# SQL query for extracting data from related tables

Tags: mysql, subquery

Although I found several similar problems but I couldn't apply them to resolve my issue.

**Problem statement**:- I have three MySql tables STUDENT,SUBJECT and STUDIES as described below:-

```
STUDENT-
rollno      Name
X1          Alpha
X2          Beta
Y1          Zeta
X3          Omega
```

here the alphabet in each rollno corresponds to student in same batch/class. E.g students X1,X2 and X3 belong to same class whereas Y1 is that of a different one.

```
SUBJECT-
Code     Title     Credits
abc     subject1     2
bcd     subject2     4
gfp     subject3     3



STUDIES-
rollno     code
X1          abc
X1          bcd
X1          gfp
X2          bcd
X2          abc
Y1          gfp
X3          abc
```

I need help in framing mysql queries for:

**a)** displaying the credits undertaken by each student. 
Like

```
Rollno       Name      Credits
X1          Alpha       9
X2          Beta        6
Y1          Zeta        3
X3          Omega       2
```

The best that I have come up is with this

```
select rollno, 
       (select sum(credits) from subject 
        where studies.code=subject.code)
      from studies;
```

But what I get are the rollno and credits displayed individually for every subject a student studies.(I haven't been able to scale my query to get the name of student from the third table yet)

**b)** Finding out the subjects which have been taken by all the students of a class/batch.
In the given scenario the answer would be

```
Batch     Subject Code     Title
X           abc           subject1
```

I can extract out distinct batches by string processing but dont know how to proceed further from that point.

**c)** Being a MySql newbie, could you also point me out to some good web resource with practice problems for learning advanced queries like these. I have gone through a few of them on the last couple days but have not found them sufficient in developing concepts required to get through my queries.

**EDIT**: Sharing the CREATE queries for the tables:-

For SUBJECT:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS subject (
code varchar(8) UNIQUE, title varchar(75) NOT NULL, 
credits int, check (credits <5),PRIMARY KEY (code));
```

For STUDENT:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student (
rollno varchar(9) UNIQUE,name varchar(50));
```

For Studies:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS studies (
rollno varchar(9) NOT NULL,code varchar(50) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(rollno) REFERENCES student(rollno));
```

Comment: can you post the create statement for all three tables?

Comment: Edited with CREATE queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for your first query, you want to join across all three tables, looking for rollno, name, and credits. So at a first pass, you need to join like this:

```
SELECT s.rollno, s.name, sb.credits
FROM student s
INNER JOIN studies st
ON st.rollno = s.rollno
INNER JOIN subject sb
ON sb.code = st.code
```

This is part of the solution - it gives you the information you want, and now you just have to use an aggregate function to tally up the credits, using SUM and GROUP BY:

```
SELECT s.rollno, s.name, SUM(sb.credits) AS credits
FROM student s
INNER JOIN studies st
ON st.rollno = s.rollno
INNER JOIN subject sb
ON sb.code = st.code
GROUP BY s.rollno, s.name
```

The second part is tougher, and there are likely other (and better) ways to do this, but here's my approach:

```
SELECT q1.batch, q1.code, sb.title 
FROM
    (SELECT st.code, SUBSTR(st.rollno,1,1) batch,
     COUNT(SUBSTR(st.rollno,1,1)) numb
     FROM studies st
     GROUP BY st.code, SUBSTR(st.rollno,1,1)) q1
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT SUBSTR(s.rollno,1,1) batch, 
     COUNT(SUBSTR(s.rollno,1,1)) numb
     FROM student s
     GROUP BY SUBSTR(s.rollno,1,1)) q2
ON q1.batch = q2.batch AND q1.numb = q2.numb
INNER JOIN subject sb
ON q1.code = sb.code
```

Some explanation: the first sub-query (q1) counts the number of students from each batch in each subject. The output from that would be:

```
abc    x    3
bcd    x    2
gfp    x    1
gfp    y    1
```

The second subquery (q2) counts the number of students in each batch, with output:

```
x    3
y    1
```

By JOINing these two subqueries, we select only those subjects where the batch and the batch count are the same:

```
abc    x    3
gfp    y    1
```

Finally, JOIN on the subject table to get the subject title included (and set the starting SELECT statement to only select batch, code, and title), giving output:

```
x      abc  subj1
y      gfp  subj3
```

Note that the last row here (y - subj3) is valid, since every member of the 'y' batch (of which there is only one) is enrolled in course gfp.

As for recommended sites and resources - that's a bit outside the scope of SO. You can find lots of good online resources by Googling 'SQL tutorial' or 'SQL online courses'. Lots of good free stuff out there.

Comment: Thanks, that works, like a charm!!. But I need to get through the description of second query many times for it to settle and make sense to me. Guess a good grip on JOIN is the first step towards formulation of complex Sql queries.